# Center JLabel within JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jpopupmenu

I know this is me being completely ocd, but I am having an issue centering the JLabel text within the JPopupMenu.

I've tried `popup.add(new JLabel("Menu",JLabel.CENTER));` and `label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);` `label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER));` but no luck.

[image: pic]

Anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the proper layout of the `JPopupMenu` such as `BoxLayout`, `FlowLayout` etc. and add the `JLabel` that is positioned based on the layout manager.

Sample code:

```
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
popup.add(new JLabel("Menu"));
```

Read more about [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) where each layout is explained in details along with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I fixed it with:

```
popup.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
JLabel label = new JLabel("Menu");
label.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```